# Checkboxes, SQL select statements & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am trying to display some rows from a database table based on choices submitted by the user. Here is my form code

```
    <form action="choice.php" method="POST" >
  <input type="checkbox" name="variable[]" value="Apple">Apple
  <input type="checkbox" name="variable[]" value="Banana">Banana
  <input type="checkbox" name="variable[]" value="Orange">Orange
  <input type="checkbox" name="variable[]" value="Melon">Melon
  <input type="checkbox" name="variable[]" value="Blackberry">Blackberry
```

From what I understand I am placing the values of these into an array called variable.
Two of my columns are called receipe name and ingredients(each field under ingredients can store a number of fruits).  What I would like to do is, if a number of checkboxes are selected then the receipe name/s is displayed.

Here is my php code.

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("****") or die(mysql_error());

$variable=$_POST['variable'];
foreach ($variable as $variablename)
{
echo "$variablename is checked";
}

$query = "SELECT receipename FROM fruit WHERE $variable like ingredients";

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
foreach ($_POST['variabble'] as $ingredients)
echo $row[$ingredients] . '<br/>';
?>
```

I am very new to php and just wish to display the data, I do not need to perform any actions on it.  I have tried many select statements but I cannot get any results to display.  My db connection is fine and it does print out what variables are checked.

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Thanks a million for replying. However, I tried correcting my own code=blank page and both solutions above ==blank pages also.  Grrrr!!  Here is one solution I tried.

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT receipename FROM fruit ";
$cond = "";

foreach($variable as $varname)$cond .= " $varname like 'ingredients' OR";
$cond = substr_replace($cond, '', -2);
$query .= " WHERE $cond";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo $row['receipename'],'<br />';
}
```

I also tried

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "24056", "project99") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("24056db2") or die(mysql_error());

$variable=$_POST['variable'];
foreach ($variable as $variablename)
{

$query = "SELECT receipename FROM horse WHERE ingredients = '".$variablename."'";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
echo $row['receipename']."<br/>";
}
}
?>
```

I suppose another way to say it, if the checkbox variable is equal to a record under the ingredients column, I wish to print out the receipename of that record.
Im nearly getting confused here mysellf, haha.

Any other ideas I could try???

Comment: Can I see the structure of your table receipename (or recipename)?

Comment: variable is mis-spelled in your code sample: foreach ($_POST['variabble'] as $ingredients)

Comment: Hi Sohnee, thanks for spotting that!  I changed it but still no difference.  

webbiedave-my table is called fruit and I have two columns,one called receipename and the other called ingredients.  The ingredients are made up of apple, banana, orange etc.
Each row has a receipename (ie Blackberry Shake) and ingredients (one or more of the ones listed above). If the ingredients checked on the checkbox are equal to a record/entry in the database I wish to display the receipe name.  Does that make sense??

Answer (score 0):

> **Correction in ur code**

```
$query = "SELECT receipename FROM fruit WHERE $variable like ingredients";

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Do u see the difference above?

Place "$query" in place of "$result" mysql_fetch_assoc($result)

> **My Solution**

```
$variable=$_POST['variable'];
foreach ($variable as $variablename)
{

$query = "SELECT receipename FROM fruit WHERE ingredients = '".$variablename."'";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
echo $row['receipename']."<br/>";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear to me, you may try the following-

```
$query = "SELECT receipename FROM fruit ";
$cond = "";

foreach($variable as $varname)$cond .= " $varname like 'ingredients' OR";
$cond = substr_replace($cond, '', -2);
$query .= " WHERE $cond";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo $row['receipename'],'<br />';
}
```

NOTE: This code is not tested